# Eclipse Indigo Speed Issues

Tags: java, eclipse, performance

After using Eclipse Indigo for around a year, suddenly the speed of an application ran in Eclipse has decreased intensely. For example, my Java game was getting 64 FPS, then suddenly 1 FPS.

Creating a new Workspace and adding all the files from the old project seems to fix it, but how would I fix this without making a new Workspace? (I've already tried deleting the Workspace's .metadata, made no difference.)

I've also tried running Eclipse with the -clean argument, no help at all.
Note that the performance issues are only when running a Java Application from Eclipse, not within Eclipse itself.

Comment: I don't understand your distinction of "from Eclipse" vs "within Eclipse"?

Comment: I mean when you click the Green 'RUN' icon, and it launches the Java Application from Eclipse.
Within Eclipse is referring to the actual Eclipse program, the code editor, which runs as fast as ever.

Comment: Do you experience this issue as soon as you open a fresh instance of eclipse in your current workspace, or does it only occur after a period of extended use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that eclipse is stuck doing background work, and causing your PC to run out of resources, resulting in paging.  Also have you installed any new plugins recently?  Some plugins can conflict with each other which could be an issue.  Check task manager to see where your resources are at while the game is running, then go from there.

Another issue I've seen is too many separate projects in 1 workspace.  Is your game the only project in your slow eclipse workspace?  If not,dedicating a workspace to individual groups of projects can help.

Comment: My Game is not the only project, but the other project has been there all the time, and not been edited for months.
I've never installed any plugins, I like to keep it simple.
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you check your system resources while running the game?  You may be able to track down a process that is hogging resources.  -Also, to ensure that other project is indeed not impacting your game, right click, and close all projects not needed to run your game.